# Loop over a list within a dictonary in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to iterate over a list that sits within a Dictionary in Ansible but find how to access the list.

My variables look like this:

```yaml
user_configs:
  hassuser:
    name: hassuser
    groups: 
     - hassuser
     - dialout
    uid: 8123
    capabilities:
      - cap_net_raw
      - cap_net_admin
```

My task looks like that:

```yaml
    - name: Update /etc/security/capability.conf to add required has capabilities
      lineinfile:
        dest: /etc/security/capability.conf
        line: "{{ item }}             {{ user_configs['hassuser'].name }}"
        owner: root
        with_items: "{{ user_configs['hassuser']['capabilities'] }}"
```

Also tried this but it doesn't see to work:

```yaml
     - name: Update /etc/security/capability.conf to add required hass capabilities
       lineinfile:
         dest: /etc/security/capability.conf
         line: "{{ item.key }}             {{ user_configs['hassuser'].name }}"
         owner: root
       loop: "{{ lookup('dict', user_configs['hassuser'].capabilities) }}"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example, `with_items` is mis-indented (it's an argument on the *task*, not on the `lineinfile` module):

```
    - name: Update /etc/security/capability.conf to add required has capabilities
      lineinfile:
        dest: /etc/security/capability.conf
        line: "{{ item }}             {{ user_configs['hassuser'].name }}"
        owner: root
      with_items: "{{ user_configs['hassuser']['capabilities'] }}"
```

In your second example you're using `loop`, which you should generally be using to replace `with_items`, but you've opted for a more complicated solution when you should be using it identically to `with_items` in the previous example:

```
    - name: Update /etc/security/capability.conf to add required has capabilities
      lineinfile:
        dest: /etc/security/capability.conf
        line: "{{ item }}             {{ user_configs['hassuser'].name }}"
        owner: root
      loop: "{{ user_configs['hassuser']['capabilities'] }}"
```

Note that you can also spell that last line like this:

```
loop: "{{ user_configs.hassuser.capabilities }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and recommandation, I'll go with the "with_items" approach